# Onmouseover plus size change

Tags: html, css, onmouseover

I'm trying to hover my mouse on an image (sweden-a.gif), and then it changes into something else (sweden-b.gif) but I want to make the new image bigger than the original image. This is my code but it doesn't work, can someone help me see what the problem is? Thanks!

```
<img class="gdp-cirlce" src="img/sweden-a.gif" style="position:absolute; height:93px;" onmouseover="this.src='img/sweden-b.gif' this.style='height:123px'" onmouseout="this.src='img/sweden-a.gif'">
```

Comment: I know you're looking for a CSS solution, but couldn't you just make the image itself bigger?

Comment: @Claudio The second image is actually bigger, but it's limited to the size of `style="position:absolute; height:93px;"`

Comment: Oh, pardon me. Didn't read your code throughoutly.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using inline styles? This would be easy to fix if you used a stylesheet.

Comment: @evilscary I just tried - it's still limited to the old dimension, when I use a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are referencing the JQuery library. If it's already referenced than try to add the above code to your document.ready function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#sweden').mouseover(function() {
$(this).attr('src', 'img/sweden-a.gif'); 
$(this).css('height', '123px');
});

});
```

Comment: Add this:  $('#sweden').mouseout(function() {
$(this).attr('src', 'img/sweden_old.gif'); 
$(this).css('height', '93px');
});

Comment: Thanks it works! An additional question: is there an easy way to make it enlarge from the center rather than the top left corner?

Comment: You can change the top and left position of the image to make it enlarge from the center when the mouse over. It depends how many pixels which you added to the image's width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do that.

HTML:

```
<img src="..."/>
```

Javascript:

```
$('img').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', your_src);
    $(this).css('width', your_width);
    $(this).css('height', your_height);
});
```

UPDATE:

[**Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/blck/tUuW9/)

Comment: HTML: `<img id="sweden">` and JavaScript:`$('#sweden').mouseover(function() {$(this).attr('src', img/sweden-a.gif); $(this).css('height', 123px);});` Is this how it works? Somehow isn't working for me...